# How to validate HelpScout webhook in python based on hash signature

Tags: python, api, hash, request

I am trying to validate webhook from HelpScout based on [HelpScout Webhooks documentation](https://developer.helpscout.com/webhooks/)

by calculating hmac hash from secret and data payload with signature from HelpScout.
Function `is_from_helpscout` works on dummy strings, but not on HelpScout incoming request. So I assume there is something wrong with passing `data` argument to the function in `handle_http`

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from base64 import b64encode
import json

class CallerValidationError(Exception):
  pass

def is_from_helpscout(secret_key: str, data: str, signature: str, encoding ="utf8") -> bool:
  """
  Calculates HMAC hash of secret key and compares to received signature
  to validate whether request is coming from HelpScout

  Params:
      -secret_key (str): secret stored on our side
      -data (str): payload data as text
      -signature (str): signature on incoming request
  Returns:
    -(bool): True if incoming request is from Helpscout, False otherwise
  """

  api_key = bytearray(secret_key, encoding)
  data = bytearray(data, encoding)
  signature = bytearray(signature, encoding)

  calculated = hmac.new(api_key, data, sha1)
  encoded = b64encode(calculated.digest())

  return encoded.strip() == signature.strip()

def handle_http(request):
  headers = request.headers
  response = request.get_json(silent=True)

  if is_from_helpscout(webhook_secret, json.dumps(response), headers["X-Helpscout-Signature"]) is False:
      print(f"!!! Looks like request coming not from HelpScout")
      raise CallerValidationError("HTTP call didn't pass secret hmac validation")
  

  print(f"Webhook type: {headers['X-Helpscout-Event']}")


  return "Done"
```